# C# Read(). How to read multiple variables and assign to var?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Exemplary code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace poleProstokata
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a;
            double b;
            double result;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value A");
            a = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value B");
            b = Console.Read();
            result = a * b;
            Console.WriteLine("result value "+result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is with Console.ReadLine(). If i wanna Read var 'A' program multiply a*a and don't want to Read var 'B' so my question is:
**How to read multiply variables from keyboard and assigning it to different variables?**

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` will return a `string` you need to parse that if you want to assign it to a `double` with either `double.Parse` or `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: `Console.Read` does not do what you are thinking it does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert and validate the `input strings` into `doubles`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace poleProstokata
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value A");
            double a;
            if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a)) {
               a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

               Console.WriteLine("Enter value B");
               double b;
               if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b)) {
                  Console.WriteLine("Result value: "+ (a * b));
                  Console.Read();

               } else {
                  Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for B!");
               }

            } else {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for A!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```